# How can I quickly check the amount of released package versions vs. beta package versions for a single devhub? And delete them?

Tags: salesforcedx

I need to delete beta package versions, but before that I want to count how many beta package versions exist for the dev hub org.
How can I quickly do this into a scripted automated way?

Can I delete all beta package versions by a script but select only those which branch is not empty and which are not descendants of latest released version 1.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the total amount of package version created from default devhub, the following command can be executed

`sfdx package:version:list --json | jq '.result | length'`

Now to count only released package versions, we can use `-r` switch like following:

`sfdx package:version:list -r --json | jq '.result | length'`

To get the amount of beta package versions, we can either subtract two numbers received or use `select` in `jq` like following:

`sfdx package:version:list --json | jq '[.result[] | select(.IsReleased == false) | .SubscriberPackageVersionId] | length'`

To delete all beta versions, which do not have ancestor of `1.0.0.1` and do not have empty branch, a following script might be used:

```
for pid in $(sfdx package:version:list --json | jq '.result[] | select(.IsReleased == false) | select(.AncestorVersion != "1.0.0.1" or .Branch != null)  | .SubscriberPackageVersionId' -r)
do
    sfdx package:version:delete -n -p $pid
done
```